# adding express API stub server to generator-angular app

Tags: javascript, express, gruntjs, yeoman

I have created an app using yeoman:

```
yo angular
```

... and the app works great, however, I would like to add to this project my own express server (without regenerating the project using `generator-mean` or the like). I am having a little trouble figuring out how to modify the Grunt file.

```
@@ -179,6 +176,18 @@ module.exports = function (grunt) {
       }
     },

+    //Express
+    express: {
+      // options: {
+      //   port: process.env.PORT
+      // },
+      server: {
+        options: {
+          script: 'stub-server.js'
+        }
+      }
+    },
+
     // Renames files for browser caching purposes
     rev: {
       dist: {
@@ -305,6 +314,7 @@ module.exports = function (grunt) {
     // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
     concurrent: {
       server: [
+        'express:server',
         'compass:server'
       ],
       test: [
```

Is what I have tried so far.

```
Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task
    Warning: Loading "cdnify.js" tasks...ERROR
    >> Error: Unable to create git_template directory: Arguments to path.resolve must be strings
    Warning: Task "express:server" not found. Use --force to continue.

    Aborted due to warnings.
```

... so it cannot find `express:server`, even though it is defined within the object passed into `grunt.initConfig`, and at the same level as `compass:server`, which does not have any issues.

What have I missed out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, there is a neat wrapper around express that makes this easy (or easier) to do: [grunt-express](https://github.com/blai/grunt-express).

Here is the [patch that I used to modify my Gruntfile](https://gist.github.com/bguiz/9042855).

You need to do this as well in the root directory of the project:

```
npm install --save-dev grunt-express path
```

HTH for anyone else doing the same!